# How to serve a static content with tomcat?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-8, tomcat9, servlet-4

I'm learning j2ee and try to develop my first web application with servlet api 4. But I have some problems with static content such as css files or images. Tomcat doesn`t skip the request to static content. How can I resolve this problem? Here is my project structure [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq2Bk.png)

and here piece of jsp file where I want to include my css files and images

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/static/images/logo.png" type="image/png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/static/css/simple-sidebar.css">`

but I have such errors in browser:
[errors list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCmOX.png)

Comment: Which request are you sending? What is the context path of your webapp? What is the contents of the war file? Provide the necessary details. Explain why you think a specific request should return the content of a specific file.

Answer (score -1):

I find solution for my problem. If you need to include some css file to your jsp page you can do just like this

`<style type="text/css">
    <%@include file="resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" %>
</style>`

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Now all your HTML pages will contain all of the bootstrap CSS, instead of simply linking to it. Why don't you answer the questions you're being asked?